# Put down a downpayment

Tags: phrases

Is it correct to say "to put down a downpayment"?

Or should it be "to put down a payment"? But that doesn't really emphasize that it's a downpayment it could be a payment of any sort.

Or maybe just say "to pay the downpayment"?

I would have thought that it's the first way but it somehow seems a bit odd...

Comment: You *put/place/make a downpayment on* a house/land/other: "Guess what? We put a downpayment on a house today!"

Comment: So "put a downpayment on blah blah blah" not "put down a downpayment on blah blah blah"

Comment: Yes, that's how we say it in AmE.

Comment: We also sometimes say, "We put down money on a house today."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most common phrase, in my experience, is *make a down payment*.

[image: Google N-Gram showing that "make a down payment" is the commonest form]

Comment: @ntomlin1996 Thanks for adding the graph.

Answer (score 1):

How about simply saying *pay down*?

> [pay down](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pay+down): to pay (part of the total price) at the time of purchase, with the promise to pay the balance on time (on installments).
>
> [down payment](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/down+payment): a partial payment made at the time of purchase, with the balance to be paid later.

Comment: Pay down? Really?

Comment: @user3306356 Yes, really!

Comment: I think this is not what OP is after, since one does not say I payed down a house  when they have put money down on one.  They might say they've paid down their house after having made loan payments for many years.

Comment: @Jim Then the OP should clarify what exactly he's looking for.

Comment: The OP specified that he was talking about a *down payment*.  "Paying (something) down" is not the same as making a down payment, and is not nearly interchangeable.  Indeed, as the OP states, *paying down* "could be a payment of any sort", as long as it does not completely eliminate the debt.

Comment: @Hellion But "to make a downpayment" is the same as "to pay down," i.e. to pay (part of the total price) with the promise to pay the balance in installments. http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pay+down

Comment: There is a crucial distinction that the dictionary entirely overlooks:  When used to indicate a 'down payment' (i.e. an partial sum paid at time of purchase), the phrasal verb "pay down" MUST be split by the amount.  If you buy a house and put 10% of the price as your down payment, you can say "I paid 10% down", but NOT "I paid down 10%".

Comment: @Hellion Sure. But what does the fact that "pay down" must be split have to do with it being different than "make a down payment?" Saying "I paid 30% down on my house" and "I made a downpayment of 30% on my house)" sounds just about the same to my nonnative ear. The same goes for "I paid down a car" and "I made a downpayment on a car." :-)

Comment: The point is, if you don't split it in that precise way, it doesn't mean the same thing.  "I paid down a car" is not a suitable replacement at all for "I made a down payment on a car".  So if you're going to suggest it, you need to clarify how it must be used in order to fit his desired meaning.

Comment: ("I paid 30% down on my house" and "I made a down payment of 30% on my house" DO mean pretty much the same thing, BECAUSE you have split "paid down" with the amount of the payment, as required to make them mean the same.)

Answer (score 0):

It's not incorrect to say 'put down a downpayment' but it has high redundancy, and *make* a downpayment is more usual.

You could also say 'put a downpayment *on* (something)' or 'put a payment down *on* (something)' and they mean the same due to the presence of 'down'.

The OED quotes Dickens: 'Dickens Mut. Fr. i. iv, I suppose a memorandum between us of two or three lines, and a payment down, will bind the bargain.'